# Lie groups having a circle subgroup

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-topology, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

in an answer to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/159728/a-simple-proof-that-parallelizable-oriented-closed-manifolds-are-oriented-bounda?rq=1) question it is said the following:

> Why Lie groups are null-cobordant (are the boundary of a compact manifold)?

I assume it refers to Lie groups of dimension (as manifolds) grater than zero.

Proof:

> "Take a circle subgroup in the Lie group. Take all the cosets. This
>   gives a fiber bundle with total space G (the Lie group) and fiber $S^1$.
>   Take the associated disc bundle. Its boundary is $G$." Q.E.D.

I assume for the context that it refers to compact Lie groups. So, my questions are:

1. Could you point to a reference (or prove if the proof is easy and not too long) where it is proved that every compact Lie group has a circle subgroup.
2. Are there any general conditions on a Lie group $G$ that guarantee that $G$ has a circle subgroup?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: 1 is explained [here](https://www3.nd.edu/~wgd/Dvi/Elementary.Lie.Groups.pdf).

Comment: Take a integer vector in $\mathfrak g$ and integrate it, you will get a circle.

Comment: A trivial comment: the trivial group is a Lie group. The answer to the original question motivating OP should be done by cases to account for this triviality (points are the boundaries of half open line segments).

Comment: @N.H. could you elaborate a bit more on your answer, please?

Comment: @AnonymousCoward that's true. Smart remark!

Comment: You probably need compactness right ? $\mathbb R$ is a Lie group and there is no subgroups isomorphic to a circle.

Comment: @N.H. That is the counterexample I was thinking of when I added the compactness hypothesis

Comment: I found a proof here : https://www3.nd.edu/~wgd/Dvi/Elementary.Lie.Groups.pdf

Comment: That reference seems great @N.H. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider a compact Lie group. A one parameter subgroup is abelian , so its closure is compact connected and abelian. But a compact connected abelian Lie group is a torus, and a torus is a product of circle. To prove that a compact abelian connected Lie group is a torus, note that its Lie algebra is abelian, so it must be a quotient of Rn (the Lie algebra) by a lattice, the kernel of the exponential map (if the Lie algebra is commutative the exponential map is a homomorphism)

Answer (score 3):

Hint: If the group is not semi-simple, then it is a semi-direct product of a semi-simple group and a non trivial torus since it is compact, done.

If the group is semi-simple  take the root system, you find a Lie subalgebra isomorphic to $sl(2)$ this means that the universal cover has a Lie subgroup isomorphic to the circle which projection on $G$ by the covering map induces a subgroup isomorphic to $S^1$.

Comment: If in a few days is not given another answer providing references or a more rudimentary approach, then I will consider the question as closed by accepting this answer.  Thanks for answering so quickly!

Comment: It is hard to imaging how you can make the theory of root systems before knowing that there exists a maximal compact torus